# openssl for zOS Unix

Tags: unix, openssl, zos

Is there an zOS Unix equivalent for the Unix openssl command?  Example

```
openssl s_client -connect in.api.dev.app.mystuff.com:443|openssl x509 -out crypto_ssl.cert
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a flavor from Rocket Software which you can port into USS.